# Xampp control panel unnecessary warning

Tags: apache, xampp

I installed xampp and changed the httpd.conf so that Apache listens to port 8080.

[image: Annoying red]

Apache can start just fine, and it listens to port 8080 just fine, but the control panel says there is a problem with port 80.

This is mostly insignificant, but because I don't like seeing red on the log, it upsets me more than it should to have it show up whenever I open Xampp control panel or whenever I start Apache.  I was wondering if you can change something to have that error not show up, maybe by changing the check to port 8080 rather than port 80.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried changing it here?

[image: Xampp settings for ports]

Comment: I am now kicking myself for not noticing that button earlier.  Thanks.